# screenshot and printscreen is not working in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, screenshot

I am unable to take screenshot / printscreen of my eclipse menu.

when I try to take screen shot of the eclipse menu file -> new -> Android project my print screen is not working.

when any of the menu is in clicked mode(i.e file,edit, run, ...)

**Note:** I am using ubuntu linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any keypress will dismiss a menu.

General workaround to this issue is to delay the actual screenshot action.

In Gnome you can issue [this command](http://www.togaware.com/linux/survivor/Gnome_Screenshot.html) in command line:

`$ gnome-panel-screenshot --window --delay 5`

and it will take a screenshot after 5 seconds delay - of the window that is current at that time

Comment: Wow its great. but when I am pressing my print screen button in my key board menu is not dismissing and No action also.

Comment: Ah, maybe is was Windows where pressing PrintScreen dismissed the menu